# Query a field in json string

Tags: elasticsearch, camunda, zeebe

I'm trying to query the field value.value which is a json string from this struct in ElasticSearch.

[image]

I wrote this query to narrow down the search:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "valueType": {
              "value": "VARIABLE",
              "boost": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "intent": {
          "value": "CREATED",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    },
  
    {
      "term": {
        "recordType": {
          "value":"EVENT",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "position": {
          "value":16185492,
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
  }
  "_source": true
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to get only record with, as example, ID_TRANSACTION=304 from field value.value. This field is a type    keyword.
Here the mapping:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you index your documents? What's the process?

Comment: Hi@Val, I'm really a newbie about ES. I got this document from Camunda Zeebe BPMN, which for every step it makes in the BPMN it records data in ES. The field I try to query is a keyword.

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping you get from `GET zeebe-record_variable_8.2.12_2023-08-31` ?

Comment: Thank you @Val, in attach the mapping I get. I'm wondering that maybe the value.value which is a string should be interpreted as a json, but now is not, so I can refer to is as value.value.N_POLIZZA as example. but not sure if it possible, again I'm really new about all of this, I'm trying to catch up reading some tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, ideally we should have an ingest pipeline with a `json` processor for parsing the `value.value` content into specific fields that you can query.

The problem, however, is that the mapping is defined with `dynamic: strict` by Zeebe, which means that it won't be possible to add new fields in your document. Also it is not possible to use `value.value` as an object containing the parsed JSON fields, because `value.value` is defined as a `keyword` and that cannot be changed.

The only way to make this happen is to change the [`record-variable` index template](https://github.com/camunda/zeebe/blob/main/exporters/elasticsearch-exporter/src/main/resources/zeebe-record-variable-template.json) present in Zeebe in order to allow new fields to be created.

If you have the rights to do it, or if you know someone who can do it for you, here is how to do it.

First, create an ingest pipeline to parse the JSON content in `value.value` into separate fields that you can query:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/value-json-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "json": {
        "field": "value.value",
        "target_field": "value.valueJson"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, modify the `zeebe-record-variable-template.json` file like this:

```
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "zeebe-record_variable_*"
  ],
  "composed_of": ["zeebe-record"],
  "priority": 20,
  "version": 1,
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "index.queries.cache.enabled": false,
      "index.default_pipeline": "value-json-pipeline"   <--- add this new setting
    },
    "aliases": {
      "zeebe-record-variable": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "value": {
          "dynamic": "strict",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 8191
            },
            "valueJson": {                             <--- add this new field
              "type": "object"
            },
            "scopeKey": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "processInstanceKey": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "processDefinitionKey": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "bpmnProcessId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "tenantId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the next `zeebe-record_variable_8.2.12_*` daily index will be created, it will have the new mapping using the new ingest pipeline that will parse the `value.value` content and put it in `value.valueJson` that you will be able to query.

Comment: thanks again @Val I'll looking into it, because it appears be the best solution but most likely the faster one as well. At the moment I query it with "query_string" : {
      "query":   "*\\\"N_POLIZZA\\\"\\:\\\"2272997\\\"*",
      "fields": [ "value.value" ]
        } as workaround. I much appreciated you effort to help me, thanks again

Comment: Let us know of this works out!